# How to run nodejs on linux platform

Tags: node.js

How to run [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) on host with linux platform?

To run node.js on localhost with windows operation system is simple

1. I download package from **nodejs.org/download/**

   and I execute Windows Installer (.msi)

   2. I go to console command line and I type

      > node file.js

and everything fine.

but in my host with linux platform I have control panel with no option to run type file exe, msi and there is no window with command line,

So how can I be able to run nodejs on my host?

I call to support of my hosting bluehost.com and they don't know.

my [Details server and control panel](http://kidslearning4fun.com/pic/)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but you're in way over your head if you expect to be able to "run type file exe, msi" on a Linux system. Have a look at the answer provided below, and contact your hosting provider if you need more assistance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that you're really *really* new to Linux. First, Linux doesn't run EXE or MSI files, at least not without Wine. The files you're looking at are Windows only. What you need is the Linux version of nodejs.

On Linux, you can either install nodejs via the package manager, or you can install it directly from nodejs, just get the version for your platform.

Now, you didn't say *which* Linux distro you're using, which is helpful information, so let's assume it's Ubuntu...

[Instructions to install nodejs via package manager](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Alternatively, you can install nodejs by downloading the latest version and [following the instructions at w3Resource.com](http://www.w3resource.com/node.js/installing-node.js-windows-and-linux.php):

- Download from the [nodejs downloads page](http://nodejs.org/download/). You want the Linux binaries, not Windows.
- Unpack the tar.gz file
- cd into the unpacked directory.
- run './configure' without the quotes
- run 'make', without quotes
- run 'make install', without quotes.

Once the install is done, check to see if the install is successful by running 'node --version', without the quotes. You should see the version number output, if it's successful.

Lastly, from the images you posted, it looks like you're using a host that gives you access to a cpanel, instead of giving you direct SSH/Shell access like a professional host would, like Amazon EC2 or Rackspace. However, in this image, it looks like you may have SSH access:

[image: SSH Access]

To install nodejs, you'll more than likely need to activate SSH/Shell access, which is the Linux command line. This may even require making a phone call or email to support, as many of these cpanel hosting providers disable SSH by default.

Alternatively, you might first ask if they can install it for you, as some hosts will do this, depending on who you're with. (You didn't say, but I'm thinking Bluehost, judging by the last screenshot).